# phpunit throws "Argument #3 (No Value) of PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter::__construct() must be a value from "never", "auto" or "always""

Tags: php, phpunit

I was just experimenting with php unit.

Here is my DependencyFailureTest class:

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class DependencyFailureTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testOne()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }

    /**
     * @depends testOne
     */
    public function testTwo()
    {
    }
}
```

But on running the command `phpunit --verbose DependencyFailureTest` it throws

> Argument #3 (No Value) of PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter::__construct() must be a value from "never", "auto" or "always".

Can anybody give an explanation for this issue?

Comment: Were you using Eclipse? I get this error using Eclipse with Makegood

Answer (score 2):

It must be a configuration issue.  I copied your code and ran it on the command line with verbose and it worked fine with version 5.4.6.

I would reinstall phpunit and ensure you have the latest version.

Also, their sample test case from their Getting Started page is:

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MoneyTest extends TestCase
{
    // ...

    public function testCanBeNegated()
    {
        // Arrange
        $a = new Money(1);

        // Act
        $b = $a->negate();

        // Assert
        $this->assertEquals(-1, $b->getAmount());
    }

    // ...
}
```

https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html

Notice the difference in your extension usage, although I don't think it is an issue, if you use their declaration as stated, it helps to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this.  Was passing --colors=true, but that is [incorrect](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/textui.html#command-line-options).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.